# Get a content type of a recycle bin item

Tags: content-type, recycle-bin

When I load list items one of the available properties is the content type and its ID:
[image]

But when I load items that reside in the recycle bin, their properties are different and no content type property is available:
[image]

Is there a way to check the content type of a deleted item without restoring it first?